# SQL Sever table is not showing value for a column in a table

Tags: sql-server, oracle, attunity

We're replicating the data from Oracle to SQL Server using Attunity.

In Oracle database , the table MEMO has a Description column which has some value.

```
(for ID = 1)
Description = 'This is test record'
```

But SQL Server is not showing that value in the Description column(where id =1), it is showing empty.

And when I'm querying the same table using Dbeaver , the Description column is showing a character 'p'.

```
Description = 'P'
```

I tried to copy in Notepad++ enabling show all characters but still no use. Help me in this strange behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 DECLARE @Result varchar(255)
       SET @Result = ''

       DECLARE @nchar nvarchar(1)
       DECLARE @position int
       SET @position = 1
       
       WHILE @position <= LEN(@nstring)
        BEGIN
            SET @nchar = SUBSTRING(@nstring, @position, 1)
        IF((ASCII(@nchar) BETWEEN 64 and 90) OR (ASCII(@nchar) BETWEEN 97 and 122) OR (ASCII(@nchar) BETWEEN 48 and 57) OR ASCII(@nchar) = 32)
             BEGIN
                    SET @Result = @Result + @nchar
             END
         ELSE 
            BEGIN
             DECLARE @asciichar varchar(10)
             SET @asciichar = ASCII(@nchar)
             SET @Result = @Result + REPLACE(@nchar,CHAR(@asciichar),'')
           END
       SET @position = @position + 1
   END

RETURN @Result

END
```